# Replacing array with new array doesn't trigger List view to reload

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have these Track objects and each Track has a [Version]. Tracks are a CoreData entity with a one to many relationship with the Version entity.

I have a List that has a section header which displays the track title, and then a row for each version associated with the track. These versions can be deleted. Currently when I delete a version, the List is not getting updated. I think my problem is I'm using @Published and @ObservedObject incorrectly here.

Whenever I delete a Version, i'm reloading the datasource of the List, however, I'm just assigning a new array rather than modifying the old one and I believe this is whats causing the view not to update. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
struct TrackItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var track: Track
    var versions: [Version]
    var expanded = false
}


class AudioData : ObservableObject {

    @Published var trackItems : [TrackItem]?

    init() {
        self.trackItems = loadTrackItems()
    }
    
    func loadTrackItems() -> [TrackItem] {
        let tracks: [Track] = DataManager.getTracks()
        var trackItems: [TrackItem] = []
        for track in tracks {
            let trackItem = TrackItem(track: track, versions: track.versions?.allObjects as! [Version])
            trackItems.append(trackItem)
        }
        return trackItems
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        self.trackItems = loadTrackItems()
    }
}

struct SubHeaderView: View {

    var version : Version
    var track: Track
    @Binding var itemDeleted: Bool

    // some code that displays Version information
    // Also a button to delete Version from [Version] of Track
    // track.removeFromVersions(version)
    // Need to update List view after version is deleted
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var audioData = AudioData()
    
    @State var itemDeleted: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             List {
                    ForEach(self.audioData.trackItems!) { trackItem in
                        Section(header: HeaderView(trackItem: trackItem), footer: EmptyView()) {
                            ForEach(trackItem.versions) { version in
                                SubHeaderView(version: version, track: trackItem.track, itemDeleted: $itemDeleted)
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.onChange(of: self.itemDeleted) { _ in
            if(self.itemDeleted) {
                // when version is deleted, reload data
                audioData.refresh()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will need minimal code to test please add the Track and Version Types as well. And if they are structs, then in the SubHeaderView the version and track are just copies not references. so what ever we do to them it will not affect the audioData.trackItems in any way

Comment: Try changing `audioData` to a @StateObject instead of an @ObservedObject. Use ObservedObject only when the object is already created outside the view and you are passing a reference of it to the view.